# facebook adding application to a page

Tags: php, facebook

The above can be done by going to app settings > view app profile page.

I'ii get a page then i can add it to tab but now when i click view app profile,it is redirecting to my app url apps.facebook.com/test.

Where am i going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you click view application profile obviously it will take to the application page, do you want to visit the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also facing same problem Facebook developer has doing some change that time...

Now it is working as previous try it again it will work.....

Eidt Apps >> View App Profile Page >> Add to my Pages >>  Select your Page..